# Is it possible to load a predefined point cloud in order to localization of the device?

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to formulate a method for indoor navigation, the objective would be any new device can localize themselves using a existing point cloud of building. which is basically having a generated point cloud and using it as existing model.
QUESTION would be: is it possible to load a point cloud to the device ?

Answer (score 0):

Tango doesn't support relocalization against an existing point cloud. In fact, Tango is using visual features to relocalize and track device's position.

To relocalize against an exsiting area, you will need to create an Area Description File (ADF) using Tango device. More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/concepts#area_learning_concepts)